# How do I Override GetHashCode and CompareTo for a Discriminated Union in F#?

Tags: f#, gethashcode, icomparable, discriminated-union

I have a simple F# discriminated union that combines a bool, a string, and a float.  I want to override the Object.Equals(arg) of this union so that I can put in an epsilon to account for precision errors when checking for float equality.  The compiler complained that I if I override this.Equals(arg), I should also override this.GetHashCode() and this.CompareTo(arg).  For these to overrides, I have no special functionality planned, so I'd simply like to call the default versions of these methods.  In my implementation now, I have three calls to GetHashCode and three calls to CompareTo for each type in my discriminated union: one for each type.

Is there a way to code the GetHashCode override with just a single call to GetHashCode?  Same question for CompareTo?  All of the types in my discriminated union implement ICompareable.

```
[<CustomEquality;CustomComparison>]
type MyType =
    | Bool of bool
    | Str of string
    | Float of float

    override this.Equals(arg) =
        let epsilon = 0.1
        match arg with
        | :? MyType as other ->
            match this, other with
            | Bool(a), Bool(b) -> a = b
            | Str(a), Str(b) -> a = b
            | Float(a), Float(b) -> Math.Abs(a - b) < epsilon
            | _ -> false
        | _ -> false

    override this.GetHashCode() =
        match this with
        // Three calls to GetHashCode.  I'd like only one
        | Bool(a) -> a.GetHashCode()
        | Str(a) -> a.GetHashCode()
        | Float(a) -> a.GetHashCode()
        | _ -> 0

    interface System.IComparable with
        member this.CompareTo arg =
            match arg with
                | :? MyType as other ->
                    match this, other with
                    // Three calls to CompareTo.  I'd like only one
                    | Bool(a), Bool(b) -> a.CompareTo(b)
                    | Str(a), Str(b) -> a.CompareTo(b)
                    | Float(a), Float(b) -> a.CompareTo(b)
                    | _ -> 0
                | _ -> 0
```

Comment: This is a bad idea... The reason the compiler insists you override `GetHashCode` and `CompareTo` is that they must be compatible with equality (equal objects should have identical hash codes and should compare the same).

Comment: In your type it seems that two values can compare equal but not have the same hash code? That sounds like a bug to me.  Personally, I would create a separate function "approxEqualTo" or similar and not mix it up with the core .NET model of equality.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could define a helper property that extracts the contents of the DU as `obj`:

```
member this.Value = 
  match this with
  | Bool(b) -> box b
  | Str(s) -> box s
  | Float(f) -> box f
```

Then you can implement `GetHashCode` just by getting the value (which involves some boxing, so it will be a bit slower) and calling the `GetHashCode` on the returned object:

```
override this.GetHashCode() =
  this.Value.GetHashCode()
```

Comment: Is there a way to use this with CompareTo?

Comment: I forgot to tag you in my comment.

Comment: @user2023861: Replace `box` with a cast to `IComparable`.

Comment: @Daniel, I tried that (`| Bool(b) -> System.IComparable b`) and I'm getting an error that says "Invalid use of an interface type"

Comment: Up-casting syntax is `b :> IComparable`.

Comment: This answers the question as posed but is inadvisable; see my comment on the question.